# Doubly-linked list insertion sort function: Why isn't my insertion sort function inserting the last two integer inputs into my linked list?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

My insertion sort function does not seem to be inserting my last two integer inputs: 15 and 8, into my doubly linked list.  My output leaves out 15 and 8.  What am I doing wrong in the insertion sort function?  I have provided my functions' code, input, and output.  Thank you.

**Here is my insertion sort function:**

```
    public void insertionSort(int p)
   {
    Node n = new Node(p);
    Node curr = head;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        head = n;
    }

    else
    {
        if(n.getProb() <= curr.getProb())
        {
            n.setNext(curr);
            curr.setPrev(n);
            head = n;
        }

        else if(n.getProb() > curr.getProb())
        {
            while(n.getProb() > curr.getProb() && curr.getNext() != null)
            {
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }

            if(n.getProb() < curr.getProb())
            {
                n.setNext(curr);
                n.setPrev(curr.getPrev());
                curr.setPrev(n);
            }

            else if(n.getProb() >= curr.getProb())
            {
                n.setNext(curr.getNext());
                n.setPrev(curr);
                curr.setNext(n);
            }
        }
    }
    size++;
  }
```

**Here is my print function**

```
    public void printSortedList()
{
    Node curr = head;

    while(curr != null)
    {
        System.out.println(curr.getProb());
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
}
```

**Here is how I input in my main function:**

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    List list = new List();

    list.insertionSort(10);
    list.insertionSort(5);
    list.insertionSort(5);
    list.insertionSort(60);
    list.insertionSort(5);
    list.insertionSort(10);
    list.insertionSort(15);
    list.insertionSort(8);

    list.printSortedList();
}
```

**Here is my output:**

```
5
5
5
10
10
60
```

Comment: What is the simplest example which fails?  Can you add a unit test to demonstrate this? What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I changed my inputs to just 3 integers
    `list.insertionSort(3);`
    `list.insertionSort(100);`
    `list.insertionSort(5);`

And the output I got was : 
    `3`
    `100`
So my function seems to be leaving out 5 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in insertion of `n.getProb() <= curr.getProb()`
In your code

```
n.setNext(curr);
n.setPrev(curr.getPrev());
curr.setPrev(n);
```

You

1. set next of n to curr -- ok
2. set prev of n to currPrev -- ok
3. set prev of curr to n -- error, you missed link to prev of curr and it still reference to curr

The same problem in your `n.getProb() > curr.getProb()` part of code.

Correct insertion:

```
           if (n.getProb() <= curr.getProb()) {
                n.setNext(curr);
                n.setPrev(curr.getPrev());
                if (curr.getPrev() != null)
                     curr.getPrev().setNext(n);//set next to curr's prev
                curr.setPrev(n);
            } else if (n.getProb() > curr.getProb()) {
                n.setNext(curr.getNext());
                n.setPrev(curr);
                if (curr.getNext() != null)
                     curr.getNext().setPrev(n);//set prev to curr's next
                curr.setNext(n);
            }
```